Optimal strategy in a number-picking game against a perfect logician?
I'm thinking about a game scenario involving three players: myself, an opponent, and a referee. Each player picks a real number between 0 and 1, and the referee will select a number randomly between 0 and 1, with each number equally likely.
The goal is to pick a number that gets as close as possible to the referee's number without going over it. The player whose number is closest to the referee's number without exceeding it wins. If both players go over or both players pick the same number, the game results in a tie.
Given that my opponent is a perfect logician, what strategy should I employ to maximize my chances of winning?

For all $x\in [0, 1]$, calculate the probability that $P(x < X)$. Imagine the opponent pick a higher number than you, what is it's probability of winning ? If the opponent picks a lower number than you, what is it's probability of winning ?

@caduk If $X$ is the random number selected by the referee, then $P(x<X)=1-x$ for all $x\in[0,1]$. If the first player chooses $x$ and the second player chooses $y<x$, then the first player wins with probability $1-x$, and the second player wins with probability $x-y$.

Now, minimize for the opponent, maximise for the player to find the Nash equilibrium.

@caduk Why are we minimizing for the opponent? It doesn't seem to be a zero-sum game (assuming the aim of our "perfect logician opponent" is to maximize their own chance of winning).

@caduk - It may not be as simple as that.  If a player always chooses $x$ with $x\ge \frac23$ then I think the other player should choose $0$, while if $x <\frac23$ then the other player should choose marginally more than $x$.  That suggests to me that there may not be a pure strategy Nash equilibrium, and instead a mixed strategy may be optimal.

@JamesMartin - it may be a fixed sum game (either one wins or both tie) and if each wanted to maximise the probability of winning minus the probability of losing then it would essentially be a zero sum game.

@Henry I think the question is explicit that we want to maximise our chance of winning, and that we are indifferent between tying and losing. If the same is true of the opponent, then it is not a fixed sum game, right?

@JamesMartin It depends on whether a tie counts as "half a win" or "no win" for each player.  I am not sure the question is clear about that.

@Henry Fair point! I've posted an answer giving what I believe is a Nash equilibrium for the non-fixed-sum case where we both care about winning, and tying doesn't count. Maybe a fixed-sum version might have an easier answer?

I assume each player is aiming to maximize their own chance of winning (and that tying does not count as winning for either player). Then one possible Nash equilibrium for the game appears to be for both players to choose their number from the distribution with density function $f$ given by
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases} \frac{1}{1-x}, &0\leq x\leq 1-\frac{1}{e}\\
0,&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}.
$$
Suppose one player plays according to that distribution. Then the expected payoff for the other player when they choose $y\in[0,1]$ is
$$
R(y):=\int_{0<x<y} (1-y)f(x)dx + \int_{y<x<1-1/e} (x-y)f(x)dx.
$$
If I've calculated correctly, $R(y)$ is constant and equal to $1/e$ on $[0,1-1/e]$, and is smaller than that for any $y>1-1/e$. So neither player has an incentive to deviate from the equilibrium. Under this equilibrium, both players have probability $1/e$ of winning the game.
Is this the unique Nash equilibrium? If not, is there another which gives one or both players a probability higher than $1/e$ of winning?
